# What is the best way to store private data in react-native?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, keychain, expo

How can i implement feature like `remember me` when authenticating via react application? I think unencrypted `AsyncStorage` isn't the best way to do it, because data is open for users. I've tried to use `realm`, but stuck into problem that cannot be resolved in android using `expo` to test application. It says that i need to compile native code for android and edit that (Add realm object creation in MainApplication.js). I don't want to compile my project while it's not released yet. How does instagram and the other RN-apps store authentication data? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 9):

> What is the best way to store private data in react-native?

I would recommend using a library like [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to store private data in [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

You can use it like that:

```
// Generic Password, service argument optional
Keychain
  .setGenericPassword(username, password)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Credentials saved successfully!');
  });

// service argument optional
Keychain
  .getGenericPassword()
  .then(function(credentials) {
    console.log('Credentials successfully loaded for user ' + credentials.username);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Keychain couldn\'t be accessed! Maybe no value set?', error);
  });
```

I hope my answer was helpful

Comment: I've seen this package. But installation of it uses native ios and android code, but not any JS api

Comment: @Herrgott Yes it use native code for technical reasons

Comment: i thought that native code using only in production. But i still didn't make `react-native upgrade`. And i partially solved this problem with using `react-native-sqlite-storage` and my own written CRUD-library

Answer (score 6):

`Expo.SecureStore` provides a way to encrypt and securely store key–value pairs locally on the device.

Use
`SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value, options)` to store and `SecureStore.getItemAsync(key, options)` to retrieve data.

Documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore

Answer (score -4):

You can use the simply storage of react-native to save the pair key=>value, the next class in TypeScript can help you:

```
export class MyStorage {

     handler: Storage;

    constructor(){
        this.handler = require('react-native-local-storage');
    }

    public saveData(key: string, value: string){
        this.handler.save(key,value).then(() => {
            this.handler.get(key).then((data) => {console.log("get: ", data)});

          })
    }

    public getData(key: string) : Promise<any> {        
      return this.handler.get(key);
    }

}
```

- saveData method storage a "value" that can be accessed by a "key".
- getData return the Promise that wrap the value saved with "key".

Comment: OP does not want to store unencrypted credentials to storage. This answer does not help with that concern.