# Is it possible to forbid import from path in eslint except one permitted includer?

Tags: eslint, linter

Can i write rule that will raise an error if one or more files are importing from one path, but permit import these files for `file.js`?

Comment: Can you tell me more about your folder structure ? 

Have you see my previous answer ? here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547657/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-private-data-in-react-native/45550361#45550361

Comment: @julien
`file.js` - can import `forbidden_file.js`|  
`file2.js` - not able to import `forbidden_file.js`|  
`folder/forbidden_file.js` - can be imported only in `file.js`

Comment: Hum I'll think about this rules

Comment: I would also be interested to know if that's possible by now...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the eslint rule `no-restricted-imports`:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports

In my case, I didn't want to allow my React components to access a 3rd party directly, but use a custom hook instead. The following rule configuration did the job:

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "group": ["@third/party"],
                    "message": "Please use the custom hook `useThirdParty` instead"
                }
            ]
        }]
```

Then in the one place where I actually want to allow this, I added the following comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-imports
import * as ThirdParty from '@third/party';
```

In order to disable the rule just for this particular line

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a rule that restricts the import

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
  'error',
  {
    patterns: [
      {
        group: ['@third/party'],
        message:
          'Importing from @third/party is only supported in *.thirdParty.ts files',
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

And then you combine that with an `override`

```
{
  files: ['src/**/*.thirdParty.ts'],
  rules: { 'no-restricted-imports': 'off' },
},
```